# .NET list access index

Tags: c#, list

Follow up question from [How to select List<> by its index and return the content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255338/how-to-select-list-by-its-index-and-return-the-content)

Can someone please comment if the elements in the list are expected to retain order? In the example above, is "Belly Buster" always expected to be at index 1 or are there cases where that might not be true?

```
List<string> pizzas = new List<string>();
pizzas.Add("Angus Steakhouse");
pizzas.Add("Belly Buster");
pizzas.Add("Pizza Bianca");
pizzas.Add("Classic Cheese");
pizzas.Add("Friday Special");

string result = pizzas[1]; // result is equal to "Belly Buster"
```

Comment: yes it can change if you modify the list, such as deleting Angus

Comment: Here is another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453006/does-a-listt-guarantee-that-items-will-be-returned-in-the-order-they-were-adde or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043039/does-listt-guarantee-insertion-order

Answer (score 0):

index starts at 0 so yes if the code stays the same..belly buster will always be at 1

Comment: Not downvoted, but even if the index starts always with 0 the item at index 0 _could_ change.

Comment: in the code provided...Belly Buster will always return index 1.

Comment: Yes, but your explanation is not sufficient, it's like someone says that the earth is round because ... because it is so. A good way to answer such questions is to provide the relevant part of the language specification or at least MSDN.

Comment: "Can someone please comment if the elements in the list are expected to retain order? In the example above, is "Belly Buster" always expected to be at index 1 or are there cases where that might not be true?"

Comment: I would have added a reason / link to MSDN. This answer almost sounds facetious. Giving you the benefit of the doubt and up-voted.